# qlogin with multiple terminal windows

Tags: nodes, qlogin

I was wondering if there is a way to do qlogin where I can have multiple terminal windows logged into the same node, ie in such a way that I could run TOP in one terminal window to monitor a job which I am also watching progress in the other terminal?

I guess a more straight forward way of asking, is can I log multiple terminals into a single qlogin job in the same way I can have multiple terminals open to the head node, or is this just something that is restricted to the head node.

I am working on a SGE centos system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$nohup <process> &` in the same window. It will put your process on the background while allowing you to run TOP or other tasks in the same terminal window. You can google nohup for more details.

Comment: I ran into the same dilemma today, and this solution made it really easy to do.